# How to bind List View Item's Context Menu to ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to bind the context menu of the listview item to the ICommand contained in my VM but unable to bind it.

I have tried the following code to display the context menu on the listview item and bind this to my VM.

**View Code**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding StudyList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudy, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding StudyVM}">
            <MenuItem Header="Lock" Command="{Binding LockCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullStatus}" Width="60"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Patient Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}" Width="350"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**VM Code**

```
public sealed class StudyVM : BaseVM {
   public RelayCommand LockCommand { get; set; }

   public StudyVM() {
       LockCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteLockCommad());
   }

   void ExecuteLockCommad() {
       //Some code to be execute when menu item clicked
   }
}
```

I have set the DataContext of my view to StudyVM. Please note that I have skipped some code (that is off-topic and works fine) related to list view item source and list view selected item.

All view part works fine like all list view items are displayed in the list, context menu display when we click on list item. But the only problem is that the ExecuteLockCommad method not execute when we click on the menu item even I bind it to the context menu item through LockCommand.

Comment: Have you checked the Output window in your Visual Studio? Check for Binding Errors. Also why do you need name for your ListView?

Comment: ListView name is removed as it not necessary.

Comment: Did you check the Output window?

Comment: Also could you share the implementation of the `RelayCommand`? And do other commands work?

Comment: Output window shows the following result: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'LockCommand' property not found on 'object' ''StudyEntity' (HashCode=1681281346)'. BindingExpression:Path=LockCommand; DataItem='StudyEntity' (HashCode=1681281346); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: RelayCommand class works fine as i have many commands for other controls like button.

Comment: Your problem is in the Data Context of the Context Menu. What you should do is to point the Command to the parent like this: `Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.LockCommand}"`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, I set the DataContext of the Context Menu as suggested by you and it works perfectly for me. thanks for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you had with your code was the `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu`.
Your current `ConextMenu` Binding would resolve the command from current context. Since the `ContextMenu` is assigned per `ListViewItem` it's `DataContext` is whatever the `ListViewItem`'s is. In your case `StudyEntity`.
This is however not a major problem, Binding can be pointed to other Context. Which in your case must be `StudyVM`. As that would be the `DataContext` of your `ListView` we can point it to through this snippet:

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.LockCommand}"
```

[Article from MSDN about RelativeSource MarkupExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/relativesource-markupextension)
Another way of getting that `DataContext` could be done through `Name`. (I know I asked you why are you using it and this is why)

```
<ListView Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding StudyList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudy, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Lock" Command="{Binding ElementName=ListView, Path=DataContext.LockCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.Resources>
    ...
</ListView>
```

This achieves the same result but, there is a down side of using names in WPF (with x:Name to be exact). [Article about memory leak](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing and further simplifying your code...

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
        <ListView Name="lvSelectStudy"  >
            <!--ItemsSource="{Binding StudyList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudy, Mode=TwoWay}"-->
            <ListView.Resources>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
                    <!--ItemsSource="{Binding StudyVM}"-->
                    <MenuItem Header="Lock" Command="{Binding LockCommand}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.Resources>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <!--<ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullStatus}" Width="60"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Patient Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}" Width="350"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>-->
            <ListViewItem>Item1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Item3</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Item4</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Item5</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

namespace WpfApp5
{
    public sealed class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public RelayCommand LockCommand { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            LockCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteLockCommand());
        }
        void ExecuteLockCommand()
        {
            //Some code to be execute when menu item clicked
        }
    }
}
```

If you put a break point in `void ExecuteLockCommand()`, it is being called after a right click on a ListViewItem...
Notice that this method, in your code, had a different name than the one defined in your ViewModel's constructor

Comment: About the different name, this is typo mistake and i have edited my question accordingly. Sorry but I didn't see any major difference between my code and ur coding suggestion. I have changed my code as per ur suggestion(removed ItemSource property of ContextMenu)but ExecuteLockCommand does not execute (Checked through break point.)

Comment: Are you using RelayCommand from GalaSoft? I am asking, because I have had issues with a "home made" RelayCommand...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ContextMenu it not in the visual tree, so you basically have to tell the Context menu about which data context to use. You can pass the datacontext through the tag property of the container as below.

```
<ListView Name="lvSelectStudy" Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource {RelativeSource Self}}">                                
            <MenuItem Header="Lock" Command="{Binding LockCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.Resources>
    ...
</ListView>
```